# Find a representation of the vector (8, -3, -3 ,2) with respect to the basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

x2 + x3 + 3x4 = 0

3x1 + 2x2 + 8x3 + 3x4 = 0

x1 − 3x2 − x3 − 10x4 = 0

Part a.) We had to find the basis for V given the equations above.

I found the basis which is T= {(0, 1, 1, 3), (3, 2, 8, 3)}.

Part b.) Use the basis to represent (8, -3, -3, 2). When I do part b I cannot seem to get an answer that is real.

Comment: $(8,-3,-3,2)\not\in\operatorname{span}\{(0,1,1,3),(3,2,8,3)\}$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).